# Console.log giving very long output about dispatch_instances in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am creating a simple app in react native wherein the text is displayed in console after the button press. After button press, I am receiving some unexpected output in console. Please suggest what can be changed or what I am doing wrong here?

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  const [enteredGoalText, setenteredGoalText] = useState();

  function goalInputHandler(enteredText) {
    setenteredGoalText(enteredText);
  }

  function addGoalHandler() {
    console.log(enteredGoalText);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.appContainer}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          placeholder="Your course goal!!" 
          onChange={goalInputHandler}
        />
        <Button title="Add goal" onPress={addGoalHandler} />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.goalsContainer}>
        <Text>List of goals....</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  appContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 50,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
  },
  inputContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 24,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "#cccccc",
  },
  textInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#cccccc",
    width: "70%",
    marginRight: 8,
    padding: 8,
  },
  goalsContainer: {
    flex: 5,
  },
});
```

I am getting the following output in console

```
"_dispatchInstances": {
    "_debugHookTypes": null,
    "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
    "_debugOwner": {
        "_debugHookTypes": [Array],
        "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
        "_debugOwner": [FiberNode],
        "_debugSource": undefined,
        "actualDuration": 0.3320891857147217,
        "actualStartTime": 829945578.402573,
        "alternate": [FiberNode],
        "child": [FiberNode],
        "childLanes": 0,
        "deletions": null,
        "dependencies": null,
        "elementType": [Function InternalTextInput],
        "flags": 8388613,
        "index": 0,
        "key": null,
        "lanes": 0,
        "memoizedProps": [Object],
        "memoizedState": [Object],
        "mode": 2,
        "pendingProps": [Object],
        "ref": null,
        "return": [FiberNode],
        "selfBaseDuration": 0.2843759059906006,
        "sibling": null,
        "stateNode": null,
        "subtreeFlags": 516,
        "tag": 0,
        "treeBaseDuration": 0.31690704822540283,
        "type": [Function InternalTextInput],
        "updateQueue": [Object]
    },
    "_debugSource": undefined,
    "actualDuration": 0.022422194480895996,
    "actualStartTime": 829945578.710574,
    "alternate": {
        "_debugHookTypes": null,
        "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
        "_debugOwner": [FiberNode],
        "_debugSource": undefined,
        "actualDuration": 0.021181941032409668,
        "actualStartTime": 829945576.637425,
        "alternate": [Circular],
        "child": null,
        "childLanes": 0,
        "deletions": null,
        "dependencies": null,
        "elementType": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "flags": 516,
        "index": 0,
        "key": null,
        "lanes": 0,
        "memoizedProps": [Object],
        "memoizedState": null,
        "mode": 2,
        "pendingProps": [Object],
        "ref": [Function forwardRef],
        "return": [FiberNode],
        "selfBaseDuration": 0.01284801959991455,
        "sibling": null,
        "stateNode": [ReactNativeFiberHostComponent],
        "subtreeFlags": 0,
        "tag": 5,
        "treeBaseDuration": 0.01284801959991455,
        "type": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "updateQueue": null
    },
    "child": null,
    "childLanes": 0,
    "deletions": null,
    "dependencies": null,
    "elementType": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
    "flags": 516,
    "index": 0,
    "key": null,
    "lanes": 0,
    "memoizedProps": {
        "accessibilityState": [Object],
        "accessible": true,
        "allowFontScaling": true,
        "autoComplete": undefined,
        "caretHidden": undefined,
        "dataDetectorTypes": undefined,
        "editable": undefined,
        "focusable": true,
        "forwardedRef": null,
        "keyboardType": undefined,
        "mostRecentEventCount": 19,
        "onBlur": [Function _onBlur],
        "onChange": [Function _onChange],
        "onChangeSync": null,
        "onClick": [Function onClick],
        "onContentSizeChange": undefined,
        "onFocus": [Function _onFocus],
        "onKeyPressSync": undefined,
        "onResponderGrant": [Function onResponderGrant],
        "onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove],
        "onResponderRelease": [Function onResponderRelease],
        "onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate],
        "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest],
        "onScroll": [Function _onScroll],
        "onSelectionChange": [Function _onSelectionChange],
        "onSelectionChangeShouldSetResponder": [Function emptyFunctionThatReturnsTrue],
        "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder],
        "placeholder": "Your course goal!!",
        "rejectResponderTermination": true,
        "returnKeyType": undefined,
        "selection": null,
        "style": [Object],
        "submitBehavior": "blurAndSubmit",
        "text": "",
        "textContentType": undefined,
        "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent"
    },
    "memoizedState": null,
    "mode": 2,
    "pendingProps": {
        "accessibilityState": [Object],
        "accessible": true,
        "allowFontScaling": true,
        "autoComplete": undefined,
        "caretHidden": undefined,
        "dataDetectorTypes": undefined,
        "editable": undefined,
        "focusable": true,
        "forwardedRef": null,
        "keyboardType": undefined,
        "mostRecentEventCount": 19,
        "onBlur": [Function _onBlur],
        "onChange": [Function _onChange],
        "onChangeSync": null,
        "onClick": [Function onClick],
        "onContentSizeChange": undefined,
        "onFocus": [Function _onFocus],
        "onKeyPressSync": undefined,
        "onResponderGrant": [Function onResponderGrant],
        "onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove],
        "onResponderRelease": [Function onResponderRelease],
        "onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate],
        "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest],
        "onScroll": [Function _onScroll],
        "onSelectionChange": [Function _onSelectionChange],
        "onSelectionChangeShouldSetResponder": [Function emptyFunctionThatReturnsTrue],
        "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder],
        "placeholder": "Your course goal!!",
        "rejectResponderTermination": true,
        "returnKeyType": undefined,
        "selection": null,
        "style": [Object],
        "submitBehavior": "blurAndSubmit",
        "text": "",
        "textContentType": undefined,
        "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent"
    },
    "ref": [Function forwardRef],
    "return": {
        "_debugHookTypes": null,
        "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
        "_debugOwner": [FiberNode],
        "_debugSource": undefined,
        "actualDuration": 0.04571723937988281,
        "actualStartTime": 829945578.690279,
        "alternate": [FiberNode],
        "child": [Circular],
        "childLanes": 0,
        "deletions": null,
        "dependencies": null,
        "elementType": [Object],
        "flags": 0,
        "index": 0,
        "key": null,
        "lanes": 0,
        "memoizedProps": [Object],
        "memoizedState": null,
        "mode": 2,
        "pendingProps": [Object],
        "ref": null,
        "return": [FiberNode],
        "selfBaseDuration": 0.018931031227111816,
        "sibling": null,
        "stateNode": null,
        "subtreeFlags": 516,
        "tag": 10,
        "treeBaseDuration": 0.032531142234802246,
        "type": [Object],
        "updateQueue": null
    },
    "selfBaseDuration": 0.01360011100769043,
    "sibling": null,
    "stateNode": {
        "_children": [Array],
        "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": [Circular],
        "_nativeTag": 3,
        "clear": [Function clear],
        "getNativeRef": [Function getNativeRef],
        "isFocused": [Function isFocused],
        "setSelection": [Function setSelection],
        "viewConfig": [Object]
    },
    "subtreeFlags": 0,
    "tag": 5,
    "treeBaseDuration": 0.01360011100769043,
    "type": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
    "updateQueue": null
}, "_dispatchListeners": [Function _onChange], "_targetInst": {
    "_debugHookTypes": null,
    "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
    "_debugOwner": {
        "_debugHookTypes": [Array],
        "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
        "_debugOwner": [FiberNode],
        "_debugSource": undefined,
        "actualDuration": 0.3320891857147217,
        "actualStartTime": 829945578.402573,
        "alternate": [FiberNode],
        "child": [FiberNode],
        "childLanes": 0,
        "deletions": null,
        "dependencies": null,
        "elementType": [Function InternalTextInput],
        "flags": 8388613,
        "index": 0,
        "key": null,
        "lanes": 0,
        "memoizedProps": [Object],
        "memoizedState": [Object],
        "mode": 2,
        "pendingProps": [Object],
        "ref": null,
        "return": [FiberNode],
        "selfBaseDuration": 0.2843759059906006,
        "sibling": null,
        "stateNode": null,
        "subtreeFlags": 516,
        "tag": 0,
        "treeBaseDuration": 0.31690704822540283,
        "type": [Function InternalTextInput],
        "updateQueue": [Object]
    },
    "_debugSource": undefined,
    "actualDuration": 0.022422194480895996,
    "actualStartTime": 829945578.710574,
    "alternate": {
        "_debugHookTypes": null,
        "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
        "_debugOwner": [FiberNode],
        "_debugSource": undefined,
        "actualDuration": 0.021181941032409668,
        "actualStartTime": 829945576.637425,
        "alternate": [Circular],
        "child": null,
        "childLanes": 0,
        "deletions": null,
        "dependencies": null,
        "elementType": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "flags": 516,
        "index": 0,
        "key": null,
        "lanes": 0,
        "memoizedProps": [Object],
        "memoizedState": null,
        "mode": 2,
        "pendingProps": [Object],
        "ref": [Function forwardRef],
        "return": [FiberNode],
        "selfBaseDuration": 0.01284801959991455,
        "sibling": null,
        "stateNode": [ReactNativeFiberHostComponent],
        "subtreeFlags": 0,
        "tag": 5,
        "treeBaseDuration": 0.01284801959991455,
        "type": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "updateQueue": null
    },
    "child": null,
    "childLanes": 0,
    "deletions": null,
    "dependencies": null,
    "elementType": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
    "flags": 516,
    "index": 0,
    "key": null,
    "lanes": 0,
    "memoizedProps": {
        "accessibilityState": [Object],
        "accessible": true,
        "allowFontScaling": true,
        "autoComplete": undefined,
        "caretHidden": undefined,
        "dataDetectorTypes": undefined,
        "editable": undefined,
        "focusable": true,
        "forwardedRef": null,
        "keyboardType": undefined,
        "mostRecentEventCount": 19,
        "onBlur": [Function _onBlur],
        "onChange": [Function _onChange],
        "onChangeSync": null,
        "onClick": [Function onClick],
        "onContentSizeChange": undefined,
        "onFocus": [Function _onFocus],
        "onKeyPressSync": undefined,
        "onResponderGrant": [Function onResponderGrant],
        "onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove],
        "onResponderRelease": [Function onResponderRelease],
        "onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate],
        "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest],
        "onScroll": [Function _onScroll],
        "onSelectionChange": [Function _onSelectionChange],
        "onSelectionChangeShouldSetResponder": [Function emptyFunctionThatReturnsTrue],
        "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder],
        "placeholder": "Your course goal!!",
        "rejectResponderTermination": true,
        "returnKeyType": undefined,
        "selection": null,
        "style": [Object],
        "submitBehavior": "blurAndSubmit",
        "text": "",
        "textContentType": undefined,
        "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent"
    },
    "memoizedState": null,
    "mode": 2,
    "pendingProps": {
        "accessibilityState": [Object],
        "accessible": true,
        "allowFontScaling": true,
        "autoComplete": undefined,
        "caretHidden": undefined,
        "dataDetectorTypes": undefined,
        "editable": undefined,
        "focusable": true,
        "forwardedRef": null,
        "keyboardType": undefined,
        "mostRecentEventCount": 19,
        "onBlur": [Function _onBlur],
        "onChange": [Function _onChange],
        "onChangeSync": null,
        "onClick": [Function onClick],
        "onContentSizeChange": undefined,
        "onFocus": [Function _onFocus],
        "onKeyPressSync": undefined,
        "onResponderGrant": [Function onResponderGrant],
        "onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove],
        "onResponderRelease": [Function onResponderRelease],
        "onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate],
        "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest],
        "onScroll": [Function _onScroll],
        "onSelectionChange": [Function _onSelectionChange],
        "onSelectionChangeShouldSetResponder": [Function emptyFunctionThatReturnsTrue],
        "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder],
        "placeholder": "Your course goal!!",
        "rejectResponderTermination": true,
        "returnKeyType": undefined,
        "selection": null,
        "style": [Object],
        "submitBehavior": "blurAndSubmit",
        "text": "",
        "textContentType": undefined,
        "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent"
    },
    "ref": [Function forwardRef],
    "return": {
        "_debugHookTypes": null,
        "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
        "_debugOwner": [FiberNode],
        "_debugSource": undefined,
        "actualDuration": 0.04571723937988281,
        "actualStartTime": 829945578.690279,
        "alternate": [FiberNode],
        "child": [Circular],
        "childLanes": 0,
        "deletions": null,
        "dependencies": null,
        "elementType": [Object],
        "flags": 0,
        "index": 0,
        "key": null,
        "lanes": 0,
        "memoizedProps": [Object],
        "memoizedState": null,
        "mode": 2,
        "pendingProps": [Object],
        "ref": null,
        "return": [FiberNode],
        "selfBaseDuration": 0.018931031227111816,
        "sibling": null,
        "stateNode": null,
        "subtreeFlags": 516,
        "tag": 10,
        "treeBaseDuration": 0.032531142234802246,
        "type": [Object],
        "updateQueue": null
    },
    "selfBaseDuration": 0.01360011100769043,
    "sibling": null,
    "stateNode": {
        "_children": [Array],
        "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": [Circular],
        "_nativeTag": 3,
        "clear": [Function clear],
        "getNativeRef": [Function getNativeRef],
        "isFocused": [Function isFocused],
        "setSelection": [Function setSelection],
        "viewConfig": [Object]
    },
    "subtreeFlags": 0,
    "tag": 5,
    "treeBaseDuration": 0.01360011100769043,
    "type": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
    "updateQueue": null
}, "bubbles": undefined, "cancelable": undefined, "currentTarget": {
    "_children": [],
    "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": {
        "_debugHookTypes": null,
        "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
        "_debugOwner": [FiberNode],
        "_debugSource": undefined,
        "actualDuration": 0.022422194480895996,
        "actualStartTime": 829945578.710574,
        "alternate": [FiberNode],
        "child": null,
        "childLanes": 0,
        "deletions": null,
        "dependencies": null,
        "elementType": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "flags": 516,
        "index": 0,
        "key": null,
        "lanes": 0,
        "memoizedProps": [Object],
        "memoizedState": null,
        "mode": 2,
        "pendingProps": [Object],
        "ref": [Function forwardRef],
        "return": [FiberNode],
        "selfBaseDuration": 0.01360011100769043,
        "sibling": null,
        "stateNode": [Circular],
        "subtreeFlags": 0,
        "tag": 5,
        "treeBaseDuration": 0.01360011100769043,
        "type": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "updateQueue": null
    },
    "_nativeTag": 3,
    "clear": [Function clear],
    "getNativeRef": [Function getNativeRef],
    "isFocused": [Function isFocused],
    "setSelection": [Function setSelection],
    "viewConfig": {
        "Commands": [Object],
        "Constants": [Object],
        "Manager": "SinglelineTextInputViewManager",
        "NativeProps": [Object],
        "baseModuleName": "RCTBaseTextInputView",
        "bubblingEventTypes": [Object],
        "directEventTypes": [Object],
        "uiViewClassName": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "validAttributes": [Object]
    }
}, "defaultPrevented": undefined, "dispatchConfig": {
    "phasedRegistrationNames": {
        "bubbled": "onChange",
        "captured": "onChangeCapture"
    }
}, "eventPhase": undefined, "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse], "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse], "isTrusted": undefined, "nativeEvent": {
    "eventCount": 20,
    "target": 3,
    "text": "T"
}, "target": {
    "_children": [],
    "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": {
        "_debugHookTypes": null,
        "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
        "_debugOwner": [FiberNode],
        "_debugSource": undefined,
        "actualDuration": 0.022422194480895996,
        "actualStartTime": 829945578.710574,
        "alternate": [FiberNode],
        "child": null,
        "childLanes": 0,
        "deletions": null,
        "dependencies": null,
        "elementType": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "flags": 516,
        "index": 0,
        "key": null,
        "lanes": 0,
        "memoizedProps": [Object],
        "memoizedState": null,
        "mode": 2,
        "pendingProps": [Object],
        "ref": [Function forwardRef],
        "return": [FiberNode],
        "selfBaseDuration": 0.01360011100769043,
        "sibling": null,
        "stateNode": [Circular],
        "subtreeFlags": 0,
        "tag": 5,
        "treeBaseDuration": 0.01360011100769043,
        "type": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "updateQueue": null
    },
    "_nativeTag": 3,
    "clear": [Function clear],
    "getNativeRef": [Function getNativeRef],
    "isFocused": [Function isFocused],
    "setSelection": [Function setSelection],
    "viewConfig": {
        "Commands": [Object],
        "Constants": [Object],
        "Manager": "SinglelineTextInputViewManager",
        "NativeProps": [Object],
        "baseModuleName": "RCTBaseTextInputView",
        "bubblingEventTypes": [Object],
        "directEventTypes": [Object],
        "uiViewClassName": "RCTSinglelineTextInputView",
        "validAttributes": [Object]
    }
}, "timeStamp": 1682788547472, "type": undefined
```

Expected console output : Text entered in input box after clicking the button

Answer (score 2):

The argument passed to the onChange handler is an `Event`; [you'll want to use `onChangeText` instead, which is passed the new text](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext):

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.textInput}
  placeholder="Your course goal!!" 
  onChange={setenteredGoalText}
/>
```